# Unable to use javascript and ajax together

Tags: ajax

I'am unable to run 2 scripts at the same time. First one is for calling the AJAX function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxindicatorstart(text)
    {
        if(jQuery('body').find('#resultLoading').attr('id') != 'resultLoading'){
        jQuery('body').append('<div id="resultLoading" style="display:none"><div><img src="ajax-loader.gif"><div>'+text+'</div></div><div class="bg"></div></div>');
        }

        jQuery('#resultLoading').css({
            'width':'100%',
            'height':'100%',
            'position':'fixed',
            'z-index':'10000000',
            'top':'0',
            'left':'0',
            'right':'0',
            'bottom':'0',
            'margin':'auto'
        }); 

        jQuery('#resultLoading .bg').css({
            'background':'#000000',
            'opacity':'0.7',
            'width':'100%',
            'height':'100%',
            'position':'absolute',
            'top':'0'
        });

        jQuery('#resultLoading>div:first').css({
            'width': '250px',
            'height':'75px',
            'text-align': 'center',
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top':'0',
            'left':'0',
            'right':'0',
            'bottom':'0',
            'margin':'auto',
            'font-size':'16px',
            'z-index':'10',
            'color':'#ffffff'

        });

        jQuery('#resultLoading .bg').height('100%');
        jQuery('#resultLoading').fadeIn(300);
        jQuery('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
    }

    function ajaxindicatorstop()
    {
        jQuery('#resultLoading .bg').height('100%');
        jQuery('#resultLoading').fadeOut(300);
        jQuery('body').css('cursor', 'default');
    }

    function callAjax()
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "fetch_data.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(res){
                    jQuery('#ajaxcontent').html(res);
            }
        });
    }

  jQuery(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        //show ajax indicator
        ajaxindicatorstart('loading data.. please wait..');
  }).ajaxStop(function () {
        //hide ajax indicator
        ajaxindicatorstop();
  });
</script>
```

and in 2nd I'm using .datafilter

```
      <li><a class="btn btn-default active" href="#" data-filter="*">All IN 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".bootstrap">Games</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".html">Softwares</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".wordpress">General</a></li>
```

When I use AJAX calling function, datafilter does'nt work so can't use it. Does anyone know how to run both at the same time?

Comment: "Unable to use javascript and ajax together" --- o_O

Comment: sorry for my bad english @zerkms